# Securing Zookeeper

Tags: security, scalability, distributed, apache-zookeeper

What are the best practices to secure the access to zookeeper?

Joining the cluster is limited (I guess) by listing the servers in the config file `/etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg`:

```
...
server.1=zk1:2888:3888
server.2=zk2:2888:3888
server.3=zk3:2888:3888
```

How about fetching data from an instance? By default zookeeper listens to all interfaces:

```
$ netstat -nltp | grep 2181
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Which means that I could fetch the data stored in zookeeper from any other server.

Comment: You can enabled Authentication and Authorization,

[Pluggable ZooKeeper authentication][1]  

[Securing Zookeeper][2] 

and , try to use **dynamicConfigFile** , for config the cluster


  [1]: http://[link]https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.2-alpha/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_ZooKeeperPluggableAuthentication[link]

  [2]: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.2-alpha/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_authOptions[link]

Answer (score 0):

Since `3.3.0` there is an `clientPortAddress` option which opens the client port on a specific IP.

I would use it like this:

```
clientPortAddress=10.0.2.15
```

This way zookeeper listens only on the private IP.